# How to replace all occurrences of a character unless it is included in a word using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of the characters 'm' or 'M' with the word " meters " unless it is part of any word such as "from" using regex.

The regex I've come up with that matches the closest to what I would like is:

```
\(?=\D)(m|M)(?=\W)/g\
```

However this still matches the 'm' in the word "from" as well as the 'm' in "15m" or "15 m"

Expected output is:

```
15M -> 15 meters
15m -> 15 meters
15 M -> 15 meters
15 m -> 15 meters
15 M and other words -> 15 meters and other words
15 m and the word from -> 15 meters and the word from
ADM -> ADM
ADM 15m adm 15 M AdM -> ADM 15 meters adm 15 meters AdM
1.5m -> 1.5 meters
45mm -> 45mm
```

How can I make the regex only select 'm' if it is NOT preceded by a character. All responses/help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies for not making a couple things clear: I am editing the expected output section of the question to show what the replacement would do using the regex. Also the regex was to target only the 'm' character and ignore the rest of the word or number it is part of. Such as 15m would become 15 meters after replacement using the regex.

Comment: does this do it? Change (m|M) to (\bm|M\b)

Comment: Very close, the only thing is that capital 'M' chars on the end of words are not filtered out. While I'm 99.99% sure this would not cause an issue, the content this will be used on includes a lot of abbreviations and calculations that may result in the ending of a word or abbreviation with a capital M. This is my fault for not clarifying that and will add an edit to the question. Thank you very much for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You match `m` in the word `from` because this part `(?=\D)(m|M)` uses a positive lookahead which asserts that what is on the right is not a digit and then match `m`. The `o` in `from` is indeed not a digit so there is a match.

Instead of an alternation you could also use a character class `[mM]` or using the case insensitive flag `/i` just use m.

```
((?:^|\s+)\d+\s*)m(?!\S)
```

- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?:^|\s+)` Assert the start of the string or match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\d+\s*` Match 1+ digits followed by 0+ whitespace chars
- `)m` Close capturing group and match m
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non-whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8IBkyB/1)

```js
let pattern = /((?:^|\s+)\d+\s*)m(?!\S)/gi;
[
  "15M",
  "15m",
  "15 M",
  "15 m",
  "15 M",
  "15 m and the word from",
  "15 M and other words with 15 meter and 9m is 999mtest",
  "test200m",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(pattern, "$1meter")))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that did it! Also appreciate the explanation, I definitely learned some more about regexs and I didn't realize you can keep part of your match and ignore another using the $1 so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a shot

```
/(?<!\D\w)(m|M)(?=\s)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/9ybCPK/1) might help to capture both <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>m</kbd> and you can simply call them using <kbd>$2</kbd>, which is the second group:

```
^([0-9\s]+)(m|M)
```

The key to this method is not to bound it from the right and only bound it from the left.

[image]